# Which table should I query?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

On the parent term page, I want to get all the nodes belonging to the parent term page and its children term. I need to output the node title, a field I created, and the node summary.

Which tables should I query? Which condition should I use?

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'product')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  // field_fenlei is the category field name.
  ->fieldCondition('field_fenlei', 'tid', arg(2))
  ->range(0, 10);

$result = $query->execute();

if (isset($result['node'])) {
  $nids = array_keys($result['node']);
  $nodes = entity_load('node', $nids);
  echo $nodes->title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to specify that you searching for nodes first (and optionally by your content type), and then filter by term:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
->entityCondition('bundle', 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_HERE')
->fieldCondition('field_game', 'tid', 5);

$result = $query->execute();
$nids = array_keys($result['node']);
$nodes = entity_load('node', $nids);
```

[How to use EntityFieldQuery](http://drupal.org/node/1343708)

Comment: your query don't have a condition of a term so it will query out all the nodes of the specified content type.

Comment: @123 you tried it ?

Comment: ps:if i want to pager the result, how do i do?thank you

Comment: i put the test code to my question.there is no any output. thank you